# How can I verify that user name starts with a letter and contains only alphanumeric characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, jquery-validate

I am using [Jquery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

Currently, I have a username, what i want to validate for this username is:

- Not blank
- Availability
- No whitespaces, I add this method:

  ```
  $.validator.addMethod("nowhitespace", function(value, element) {
       return this.optional(element) || /^\S+$/i.test(value);
  }, "  No white space please");
  ```
- Alphanumeric

  ```
  $.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
       return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i.test(value);
  }, "  Alphanumeric. Only numbers and alphabet allowed");
  ```
- First characters must be alphabet, cannot be numeric.

I am stuck at the last validation. How to write a regular expression to validate first character MUST be alphabet?

BTW:

The no whitespace seems having problem. I tried my script, 1 whitespace its allowed, but 2 whitespaces not allowed, why?

Comment: your regexp for the no-whitespace appears to be correct at first glance...?

Comment: Why do you specify `i` for your patterns?

Comment: Does jQuery/JavaScript not provide the regex standard group names like [ALPHNUM]?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]+$/
```

for the *alphanumeric* method.

This matches any string which consists of a letter followed by one or more alphanumeric characters. This assumes that single character user names are not allowed. If you do want to allow single character user names, change the pattern to:

```
/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$/
```

This way, there is no need for a separate check for the first character. Incidentally, this should also obviate the need for the whitespace check as a string that consists entirely of alphanumeric characters cannot contain any whitespace by definition.

Comment: this answer beat mine out by a few seconds, with the exact same pattern. What it is doing is requiring a single char from [A-Za-z] and then requiring it to be followed by one or more chars from [A-Za-z0-9].  You could change the "+" to a "*" if you wanted to allow a username to be only one letter.

Comment: weird, cant choose your answer as the best answer. Is it something wrong with my browser?

Comment: Sure, I will keep trying until it accepts. I am the one who should say "thank you", you solved the problem that I might take days to solve. Thanks :)))))

Answer (score 2):

```
value.substr(0, 1).match(/[A-Za-z]/) != null
```

Comment: Um.. Is that jquery or just a normal javascript method?