# What's the correct regex to allow a dash symbol when using the jquery.validator.addMethod?

Tags: jquery, regex

I just can't get this figured out. I'm using `jquery.validator.addMethod`. Currently I have the following:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\w+$/i.test(value);
}, "Letters, numbers, and underscores only please");
```

This allows letters, underscores and numbers. But what I'd need to allow instead of underscore would be a dash (`-`).

I'm very new to regex and I've been trying to figure out this simple problem but I just can't find a way to do it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need to add a method for this? I think you just need to specify the rule: `pattern: /^[a-z0-9\-]+$/i` and the message: `pattern: "Letters, numbers, and underscores only please"`.

Comment: If there's another way, I didn't know about it. Going to look into it straight away :)

Comment: I have added an answer just in case you find that approach useful in the future.

Comment: Indeed, much simpler like that. Thank you, I will use that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "dash" try this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z0-9\-]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Letters, numbers, and dashes only please");
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems to accept everything though now that I test it. signs like: @_ etc  are going through as well.

Comment: I'd accept with pleasure :)  But like I said, it doesn't work. It doesn't limit it to the letters, numbers and dashes only, instead whatever symbol is accepted as it is. For example @ _

Comment: Try to return only true/false with the regex: `return /([a-z0-9\-]+)/i.test(value);`

Comment: Used this one instead and it works: /^[a-z0-9\-\s]+$/i.test(value); Found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326910/jquery-validator-validate-alphanumeric-space-and-dash if you could edit it to the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve the same result by specifying a `pattern` rule and message as follows:

```js
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
      alphanumdash: {
        required: true,
        pattern: /^[a-z0-9\-]+$/
      }
    },
    messages: {
      alphanumdash: {
        required: 'AlphaNumDash is required',
        pattern: 'Letters, numbers, and dashes only please'
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<form id="test">
  <input type="text" name="alphanumdash" /><br/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```